# Redefining special methods in Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def __len__(self):
        """
        Return number of elements sorted in array
        """
        return self.n
```

To my understanding, we are redefining what the method `len` will return for our class. Am I correct or there is a bigger picture?

Comment: `len` It is not a method of your class. What you are doing is implementing a protocol. The function `len` knows (or expects) that the object it takes as a parameter will have that `__len__` method implemented so it will call it.
You can think of it as how interfaces work in other languages.